# Single source worksheet, and multiple pivot tables using filtered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, multiple-instances

How does one create a workbook, where one worksheet is the master source data, but multiple pivot tables need to be created with the same set of "row labels" and "summed values", but different filters set on the master source data.

For example, say my master source looks like this :

```
Account      Region     Quota  Actuals  Upside
----------------------------------------------
 ACME co     Europe       120     130      10
 Dodo Inc    Americas      80      70       5
 Imagine co  Europe        90      60      20
 ABCD plc    Asia          50      80       0
 Spooky Inc  Americas     200     190      20
 XYZ plc     Asia         110     100      15
```

And, I'd like a separate pivot table, per *Region*, given *shortfall* (*Quota* minus *Actuals*) and potential of that being offset by the *Upside*.

This is a simplification of a much bigger and more complex table, but hopefully it gives the picture. I'd prefer not to create copies of the same master data, and using multiple copies, it is trivial to do the multiple pivots.

I have Microsoft-Excel-2010, but anything that works in 2007/2010 is good for me.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I have found the answer to this question. What I had to do was to use the standard pivot table creation mechanism, using the Insert Pivot-Table wizard, after selecting the source table.

In the "Pivot Table Field List" sub-window that appears on the right side of the worksheet with the pivot table being designed, one needs to drag the fields (like *Region* in my case) to the **Report Filter** box, and then make the selection of the Region value from the drop-down list, while creating rest of the pivot table. Once one such pivot table is created, I could just copy paste the entire pivot table into another worksheet, and make a different region selection.